# cannt able to compile bcc

Tags: clang, llvm, bcc-bpf

I have tried many times to build bcc with LLVM but always failed.

CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:99 (find_package):
Could not find a package configuration file provided by "LLVM" with any of
the following names:

```
LLVMConfig.cmake
llvm-config.cmake
```

Add the installation prefix of `"LLVM"` to `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` or set
`"LLVM_DIR"` to a directory containing one of the above files.  If `"LLVM"`
provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
installed.

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

```
See also "/root/bcc/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/root/bcc/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

Comment: Have you checked the issues on the BCC repositories? You might have found [this one for example](https://github.com/iovisor/bcc/issues/1975), which would advise to have a look at the [INSTALL.md](https://github.com/iovisor/bcc/blob/master/INSTALL.md) file to make sure that you have all dependencies installed. Have you checked that?

Comment: Yes i am following the same this install.md  file. i have checked it.

Comment: In that case I would suggest opening a new issue on the BCC repository, and providing more details (Linux distribution, clang/LLVM versions installed, the dependencies you installed, etc.). The folks working on the project are more likely to be able to help you; and there's not enough information to help here if you indeed have installed all required dependencies.

Comment: The suggestion is a good one: Add the installation prefix of "LLVM" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "LLVM_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files. If "LLVM" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been installed.